# Hyperledger fabric: How to add new organization and a peer to existing Hyperledger Composer single organization fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am new to Hyperledger fabric.

I was able to use one tutorial to:

1. install prerequisites and hyperledger composer development tools
2. create a fabric network
3. install/deploy business network
4. create an angular front end

However, the fabric network that got created has only one organization and a peer. For my POC, I need three organizations with one peer each.

How can I add additional organizations and peers in existing fabric network?

Comment: This topic is actually covered in fabric docs. References: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/channel_update_tutorial.html.

Comment: Thank you Mrudav for the link.
I want to mention that I have used Hyperledger Composer development tools - Composer CLI, Composer rest server etc. The hyperledger fabric that is installed has only one organization as said in my question. 

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html

Comment: Is it possible to add more organizations to the fabric network that is provided by Hyperledger composer tools?

Comment: I have used following links for creating development environment - 
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html

Comment: I was able to create multi-organization network in the Hyperledger composer development environment using following link - 

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-website/jekylldocs/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.md

This link opens up a tutorial that provides steps to be undertaken to achieve the above requirement. According to the tutorial, the fabric-dev-server single organization fabric network should be replaced by multi-origanization BYFN.

Comment: The issue is resolved for me.

Comment: Hi @devman Can you explain the steps that you followed? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, @Pranjal, see the steps in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps

**A)    Install prerequisites**

```
(Run in dir - dev5@ubuntu:~$)
```

1)  You can start by updating and upgrading the package manager

> ```
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo dpkg --configure -a
> ```

2   Install curl

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

3   Check curl version

```
curl --version
```

4   Install Go Language

```
$ cd $HOME/
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf go1.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
$ mkdir $HOME/gopath
$ export GOPATH=$HOME/gopath
$ export GOROOT=$HOME/go
$ export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
$ go version
```

5   Download the prerequisites file using the following commands    \

```
curl -O https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/prereqs-ubuntu.sh
```

6   Install libltdl-dev

```
apt-get install libltdl-dev
```

7   Open preres-ubuntu.sh file for reference. Get following commands from the file. Check if they match. If no, then use the one in the file.

8   This command is at string "Array of supported versions". Run it

```
declare -a versions=('trusty' 'xenial' 'yakkety', ‘bionic’);
```

9   Update the CODENAME var that is used in future

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    source /etc/lsb-release || \
        (echo "Error: Release information not found, run script passing Ubuntu         version codename as a parameter"; exit 1)
    CODENAME=${DISTRIB_CODENAME}
else
    CODENAME=${1}
fi
```

10  Check if version is supported

```
if echo ${versions[@]} | grep -q -w ${CODENAME}; then
    echo "Installing Hyperledger Composer prereqs for Ubuntu ${CODENAME}"
else
    echo "Error: Ubuntu ${CODENAME} is not supported"
    exit 1
fi
```

11  Update the package manager

```
sudo apt-get update
```

12  Install Git

```
sudo apt-get install -y git
```

13  Install nvm dependencies

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential libssl-dev
```

14  Execute nvm installation script

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
```

15  Set up nvm environment without restarting the shell

```
export NVM_DIR="${HOME}/.nvm"
        [ -s "${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh" ] && . "${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh"
        [ -s "${NVM_DIR}/bash_completion" ] && . "${NVM_DIR}/bash_completion"
```

16  Install node

```
nvm install --lts
```

17  Configure nvm to use version 6.9.5

```
nvm use --lts
nvm alias default 'lts/*'
```

18  Install the latest version of npm

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

19  Add Docker repository key to APT keychain

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

20  Update where APT will search for Docker Packages

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu 
${CODENAME} stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

21  Update package lists

```
sudo apt-get update
```

22  Verifies APT is pulling from the correct Repository

```
sudo apt-cache policy docker-ce
```

23  Install Docker

```
sudo apt-get -y install docker-ce
```

24  Install docker compose

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.13.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" \
-o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

25  Install python v2 if required

```
set +e
COUNT="$(python -V 2>&1 | grep -c 2.)"
if [ ${COUNT} -ne 1 ]
then
   sudo apt-get install -y python-minimal
fi
```

26  Install unzip, required to install hyperledger fabric.

```
sudo apt-get -y install unzip
```

27  Upgrade docker-compose as >= 1.18 is needed

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.18.0/docker-    compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

28  Clone the fabric-samples from the github

```
git clone https://github.com/mahoney1/fabric-samples.git
```

**B Install hyperledger composer development tools**
    (Run in dir - dev5@ubuntu:~$ )

1   Install the CLI tools -

```
    composer-cli    npm install -g composer-cli
    composer-rest-server    npm install -g composer-rest-server
    generator-hyperledger-composer  npm install -g generator-hyperledger-composer
    Yeoman  npm install -g yo
```

2   Set up your IDE

```
    https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Open VSCode, go to Extensions, then search for and install the Hyperledger Composer extension from the Marketplace.
```

**C Run fabric network**

```
(Run in dir - dev5@ubuntu:~$ fabric-samples)
```

1   Change directory to fabric-samples

```
cd fabric-samples
```

2   Download the platform binaries, including cryptogen using this command (three parameters needed for the bash command):

3   To work with current fabric level, run this command

```
git checkout multi-org
```

4   Check downloaded binaries. Change directory to bin

```
cd bin
ls
```

5   Change to  first-network directory

```
cd ../
cd first-network
ls
```

6   Generate the required certificates and articates for your first network

```
./byfn.sh -m generate
```

7   Start the fabric

```
sudo ./byfn.sh -m up -s couchdb -a

On error - "Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?"
```

Check if docker is active

```
sudo systemctl is-active docker
```

If not active, then
    sudo docker images
    sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
    sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
    sudo docker --version

To start docker, run

```
sudo service docker restart
```

8   Start the fabric again

```
$ sudo ./byfn.sh -m up -s couchdb -a
```

9   If still the network fails to start, then restart the channel

```
sudo ./byfn.sh -m restart -c mychannel
```

**D Run fabric network**

```
*Organization Org1 is represented by Alice  
Organization Org2 is represented by Bob*
```

1   Create a temporary working directory (and subdirectories) to manage the Composer connection profiles and key/certificate files

```
mkdir -p /tmp/composer/org1
mkdir -p /tmp/composer/org2
```

2   Create a base connection profile that describes this fabric network that can be given to
    Alice and Bob
    Go to /tmp/composer

```
cd /
cd tmp
cd composer

Open editor and copy paste the contents of byfn-network.json sheet in the editor and save it as byfn-network.json   

nano
```

3   Open byfn-network.json and replace all instances of the text INSERT_ORG1_CA_CERT with the CA certificate for the peer nodes for Org1

[Run in dir - dev5@ubuntu:~$ fabric-samples/first-network]

3.1 Run the command and get the certificate from the generated .pem file so that it can be embedded into the above connection profile

3.11    Go to first network folder
    cd /
    cd home/dev5
    cd fabric-samples/first-network

3.12    Execute the command to generate /tmp/composer/org1/ca-org1.txt

```
awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt > /tmp/composer/org1/ca-org1.txt
```

3.13    Open ca-org1

3.14    Copy the contents of the file /tmp/composer/org1/ca-org1.txt and replace the text INSERT_ORG1_CA_CERT in the .json file

4   In the same .json file - you need to replace all instances of the text INSERT_ORG2_CA_CERT with the CA certificate for the peer nodes for Org2

4.1 Run the command and get the certificate from the generated .pem file so that it can be embedded into the above connection profile

4.11    Execute the command to generate /tmp/composer/org1/ca-org2.txt

```
awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt > /tmp/composer/org2/ca-org2.txt
```

4.12    Open ca-org2

4.13    Copy the contents of the file /tmp/composer/org1/ca-org2.txt and replace the text

```
INSERT_ORG2_CA_CERT in the .json file
```

5   Replace all instances of the text

```
INSERT_ORDERER_CA_CERT with the CA certificate for the orderer node
```

5.1 Run the command and get the certificate from the generated .pem file so that it can be embedded into the above connection profile

5.11    Execute the command to generate /tmp/composer/org1/ca-orderer.txt

```
awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt > /tmp/composer/ca-orderer.txt
```

5.12    Open ca-orderer.txt

5.13    Copy the contents of the file /tmp/composer/org1/ca-orderer.txt and replace the text INSERT_ORDERER_CA_CERT in the .json file

6   Save this file as /tmp/composer/byfn-network.json
    This connection profile now describes the fabric network setup, all the peers, orderers and certificate authorities that are part of the network, it defines all the organizations that are participating in the network and also defines the channel's on this network. {{site.data.conrefs.composer_full}} can only interact with a single channel so only one channel should be defined.

7   Customize the connection profile for Org1

```
In the connection profile /tmp/composer/byfn-network.json between the version property and just before the channel property, add this block that specifies the organization that alice belongs to, in a client section with optional timeouts. Save the connection profile file as a NEW file called byfn-network-org1.json in /tmp/composer/org1/      

"client": {
    "organization": "Org1",
    "connection": {
        "timeout": {
            "peer": {
                "endorser": "300",
                "eventHub": "300",
                "eventReg": "300"
            },
            "orderer": "300"
        }
    }
},
```

8   Customize the connection profile for Org2
    In the connection profile /tmp/composer/byfn-network.json between the version property and just before the channel property, add this block that specifies the organization that bob belongs to, in a client section with optional timeouts. Save the connection profile file as a NEW file called byfn-network-org2.json in /tmp/composer/org2/

```
"client": {
        "organization": "Org2",
        "connection": {
        "timeout": {
            "peer": {
                "endorser": "300",
                "eventHub": "300",
                "eventReg": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
```

9   Copy the certificate and private key to /tmp/composer/org1 for Org1

```
export ORG1=crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    cp -p $ORG1/signcerts/A*.pem /tmp/composer/org1
    cp -p $ORG1/keystore/*_sk /tmp/composer/org1
```

10  Copy the certificate and private key to /tmp/composer/org2 for Org2

```
export ORG2=crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
    cp -p $ORG2/signcerts/A*.pem /tmp/composer/org2
    cp -p $ORG2/keystore/*_sk /tmp/composer/org2
```

11  Creating business network cards for the administrator for Org1

```
composer card create -p /tmp/composer/org1/byfn-network-org1.json -u PeerAdmin -c /tmp/composer/org1/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem -k /tmp/composer/org1/*_sk -r PeerAdmin -r ChannelAdmin -f PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1.card
```

12  Creating business network cards for the administrator for Org2

```
composer card create -p /tmp/composer/org2/byfn-network-org2.json -u PeerAdmin -c /tmp/composer/org2/Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem -k /tmp/composer/org2/*_sk -r PeerAdmin -r ChannelAdmin -f PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2.card
```

13  Import the business network cards for the administrator for Org1

```
composer card import -f PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1.card --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1
```

14  Import the business network cards for the administrator for Org2

```
composer card import -f PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2.card --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2
```

15  Create business network archive file for the desired business network

16  Install the business network onto the peer nodes for Org1

```
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 --archiveFile trade-network.bna
```

17  Install the business network onto the peer nodes for Org2

```
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2 --archiveFile fta-fab-net.bna
```

18  Define the endorsement policy for the business network
    Create an endorsement policy file using content of sheet endorsement-policy.json and save it in /tmp/composer/ with name endorsement-policy.json

```
The endorsement policy you have just created states that both Org1 and Org2 must endorse transactions in the business network before they can be committed to the blockchain. If Org1 or Org2 do not endorse transactions, or disagree on the result of a transaction, then the transaction will be rejected by the business network.
```

19  Retrieve business network administrator certificates for Org1
    Run the composer identity request command to retrieve certificates for Alice to use as the business network administrator for Org1

```
composer identity request -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -u admin -s adminpw -d alice
```

20  Retrieve business network administrator certificates for Org2
    Run the composer identity request command to retrieve certificates for Bob to use as the business network administrator for Org2

```
composer identity request -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2 -u admin -s adminpw -d bob
```

21  Start the business network

```
composer network start -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -n fta-fab-net -V 0.1.14 -o endorsementPolicyFile=/tmp/composer/endorsement-policy.json -A alice -C alice/admin-pub.pem -A bob -C bob/admin-pub.pem
```

Note: the version number of bna file should be used in this command

If the command fails then check the docker, start the fabric n/w, install the bna file, check if tmp/compser is present

Once the business network is started. both Alice and Bob will be able to access the business network, start to set up the business network, and onboard other participants from their respective organizations.

Alice and Bob must create new business network cards with the certificates that they created in the previous steps so that they can access the business network.

22   Creating a business network card to access the business network as Org1

Create a business n/w card

```
composer card create -p /tmp/composer/org1/byfn-network-org1.json -u alice -n fta-fab-net -c alice/admin-pub.pem -k alice/admin-priv.pem
```

Import the business network card

```
composer card import -f alice@fta-fab-net.card
```

Test the connection to the blockchain business network

```
composer network ping -c alice@fta-fab-net
```

23   Creating a business network card to access the business network as Org2

Create a business n/w card

```
composer card create -p /tmp/composer/org2/byfn-network-org2.json -u bob -n fta-fab-net -c bob/admin-pub.pem -k bob/admin-priv.pem
```

Import the business network card

```
composer card import -f bob@fta-fab-net.card
```

Test the connection to the blockchain business network

```
composer network ping -c bob@fta-fab-net
```

24  Start the RESTful API   composer-rest-server
    Answer the questions as given below:
    Enter the name of the business network card to use: alice@fta-fab-net
    Specify if you want namespaces in the generated REST API: never use namespaces
    Specify if you want to use an API key to secure the REST API: No
    Specify if you want to enable authentication for the REST API using Passport: No
    Specify if you want to enable the explorer test interface: Yes
    Specify a key if you want to enable dynamic logging: dts
    Specify if you want to enable event publication oevr websockets: Yes
    Specify if you want to enable TLS Security for the REST API: No

Open browser and go to URL

```
http://localhost:3000/explorer
```

This will open rest server