# Implement the distributed-decentralised ledger for a hyperleder network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

Did a small example using the hyperledger composer and then used the composer-rest-server to integrate it with GUI. So in the case of identity, only admin is there. There is also documentation to create and issue other identities to login into the business networks.

But still, the problem is it's only in a **single peer**, meaning **my local machine**. To my understanding, for the hyperledger to function as decentralized and distributed ledger system, additional peers have to be added to the channel and then states gets synced in those peers. Hence if one node is down, details can be obtained from other nodes.

I checked some links such as [this](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/extending-hyperledger-fabric-network-adding-a-new-peer-4f52f70a7217) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023759/hyperledger-fabric-how-to-add-new-organization-and-a-peer-to-existing-hyperledg). But all of these point to the things that :

- Existing network should be stopped and teared down.
- The IP address of the second machine should be manually added to the docker.yml file and then have to be restarted.

My doubts are :

- But on doing this, won't the existing ledger stated be cleared? All the data are gone.
- So before even creating a dApp using hyperledger, we have to include all the IP address of the machine in the yml and start the network?
- How to actually implement the distributed-decentralised ledger system for a hyperleder network?

**UPDATE :**

I have checked the links mentioned by Paul O'Mahony. The links explains about the peer addition steps. Overall what happens there is :

- downloaded the `fabric sample` as the fabric extension is only possible through the cryptogen version appropriate to the Fabric version.
- Currently contains order, org1 & org2 (with 2 peers each).
- To add a new peer along with its couchdb, changed the template count in the crypto-config.yaml and created crypto material for the new peer using the `extend` command.
- Then using the docker composer file to spawn a new peer and its couchdb. This will create new containers.
- Finally the created peers should be joined to the existing channel for the couch db to get sync. The adding to existing channel is via logging into the docker container and typing some cli commands and adding the peer to channel via `channel join` command.

Is this recommend way to add peers to the channel ? Suppose i am creating a network and wanted to add peers to the channel based on a condition. Like a user/users can add themselves to the network through a login via composer playground and act as a peer. So i have to follow the same steps to do it ? Is this the recommended way ?

Supporting link : https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric?msg=KgxFegcZyKEPdo4v2

Comment: The user has asked a similar question on Rocketchat - can be tracked here -> https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/composer?msg=sjn5z8GTy33x2ps99

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony: Thanks for the reply. I am checking it now. Can the peer be added from external IPs too?

Comment: yes, see examples below - someone has written a useful blog for a Fabric network across different physical machines https://medium.com/1950labs/setup-hyperledger-fabric-in-multiple-physical-machines-d8f3710ed9b4 includingwhere to configure the IP for additional peer. There is also a multi-org tutorial https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org that shows two organisations (two peers in each) interacting in the same business network (and making updates to the same ledger on the Fabric channel configured)

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony : I have updated the question. Please take a look at it

Comment: 1. You can add a peer without tearing down existing 2. the new peer should be accessible by the other containers by name/IP. 3. Users are not 'added' to a Fabric channel - in Composer, you create a business network card (see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/playground/id-cards-playground and https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/participantsandidentities ) to understand more. They interact with a business network (smart contract, dApp), deployed to Fabric with that card (that contains their blockchain identity - not to be confused with app user id).

Comment: See this tutorial https://medium.com/@mahoney_33893/hyperledger-composer-adding-another-organization-to-an-existing-running-multi-organization-fff5c8104a82 for further insights (adding a 3rd Org, with its 2 peers, to an existing running network). Recommended (normal) way is an Org will add its own  peer(s) and build own biz network cards, in an existing blockchain network. Peer channel join is the method https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/commands/peerchannel.html

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony : The tutorial is neatly laid out. I am getting the hang of it.  
However, while adding the org3 and assigning the admin I am getting the error "Error: failed to request identity. Error trying to enroll user and return certificates. Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9054]
Command failed".

Comment: Also in the json file, we are adding org3 with the url as localhost and port number. So can i replace that with org in another laptop. Replacing the localhost with the ip and also the certificates and keys from the other machine ?